# Position fixed snaps -15 px on scroll

Tags: html, css, css-position

Having a weird issue of position fixed not working properly. You can see it here: https://randohinn.com/uus/ When you scroll on your computer, the header satys in place ok, but on mobile, once you scroll, it moves by some 15 pixels so that the top half until my name letters start is not appearing. Why is it so and how could I fix it?

Comment: Post your code in the question, don't link to your site. Your site will change, which means this question will become worthless to future readers.

Comment: @Rando Simply opening console would give you an hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not be obvious, but the extra height is caused by extra width. Your `<body>` is wider than `100vw` and causes a double-scroll effect, causing the fixed header to move around as you scroll the body.

You placed the following CSS rules in your `main.css`:

```
.row {
   ...
  margin-right: -.5rem;
  margin-left: -.5rem; 
}
```

You probably want to wrap them inside a `@media(min-width: 768px) {}` query, similar to how Bootstrap does it.

Or, you can just set them to `0` on mobile:

```
@media(max-width: 767px) {
  .row {
     margin-right: 0;
     margin-left: 0; 
   }
 }
```

Just make sure you place this after the ruleset mentioned above.

The above fixed the issue for me in emulator, but the emulator is not always accurate. If you still experience the double scroll, use

```
@media(max-width: 767px) {
  body {
    width: 100vw;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yup, that does the trick. Stupid flexbox-grid being smarty about the margins.